# Container to Obfuscate

Tags: containers, azure-devops

I have a few CI environment in VSTS.  One for dev, QA, staging, and production.  my builds are created in the cloud by VSTS build agents.  these builds are not obfuscated by design and need to be deployed to my dev and test environments as such.  When they are approved by QA in the test env, they go to staging.  What I need to have happen is for the build to be obfuscated before being put in this environment.  Is it possible for me to run a docker container in VSTS release pipeline to obfuscate the build in the container and then download the result in a deployment group?

My main questions are boiled down to this:

I would like to have a container image in the cloud running a tool installed on the image. During my VSTS release pipeline, I would like for my release agent to pull down this image, pass in the build artifact, and then do something with the results of running my artifact through this tool. I have an Azure subscription. I've tried reading the documentation but I'm confused as to what I need to set up. This container is not hosting any web app, but is being used as a way to run my tool locally on the release agent. I see that I can run a docker run command as a VSTS pipeline action. What do I need to set up on my azure subscription to host this image for the VSTS agent to pull it down?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "obfuscating the build" and why you would want to do it. Do you mean the output of the build results when your VSTS pipeline is ran? Is there sensitive data in your build results?

Comment: The decision to obfuscate is not mine to make, has already been made and is not up for debate.  I'm automating a manual process.  Some env doesn't need obfuscation so that debugging is easier.  By obfuscate the build i mean minnify the produced artifacts (exe, dlls, configs) and prevent people from dot peeking the exe and being able to eaisly follow what is going on.  We already have a program on another svr that does this manually.  can i put it in a container and run it as part of the VSTS relase pipeline.

Comment: I fail to see the point of obfuscation here.

Comment: our obfuscation does more than just obfuscate, it also combines all our managed dlls into one exe, yes making the exe bigger but also easier to manage along with a few other niceties.  Just because you don't see the point doesn't mean i don't have the question.